# Need help putting a background image in html and css

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to put a background image on a website using html and css, I've watched youtube videos but it never works for me. I was wondering if anyone could help point out what I've been doing wrong. Thank you!

Tried putting an image as a background for a website but whenever I save and reload the website it never appears and is just blank.

[I forgot to add the speech marks thing here, but even when I added it, it still never worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAuwA.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: you need to put your code instead of using an image, so developers can help you fast and easier,

anyway you're body is empty, so it's width & height = 0 so the background isn't showable, at least set width and height and try to reload the page it will show your Background

Answer (score 0):

update the path to

```
background-image: url(../ronaldo.jpg);
```

go through this article for a better understanding  of using path [absolute-vs-relative-paths](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong path. Your image is not in the same folder as your css file. Put a correct path, try this: `background-image: url(../ronaldo.jpg);`.
If it still doesn't work, tru putting the path in between of *" "* like this:
`background-image: url("../ronaldo.jpg");`

Comment: When I do that it had allowed me to select the file, however it still appears as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing in **"/"** in the **url brackets** and the intelisense should appear.
It should give you all possible images in your folder.